# Is it possible to display csv file as a table in Markdown?

Tags: csv, datatable, path, markdown, tabular

Is it possible to display a table in Markdown by referencing the path to a csv?
Or any other tabular file formats?

Comment: maybe you can use: https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-markdown.htm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is intended for RMarkdown. Sorry for the mess.

Yes, you can. Use the function `read.csv`

**A code chunk:**

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(flextable) #you can use another table library, if you want
flextable(read.csv("Your_working_directory\\test.csv"))
```
````

Also, you can read a lot of files' types with `read.file` and with `read.table`

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.12/topics/read.file
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/read.table

Comment: well this will work if you are using RMarkdown. With "normal Markdown" this is not possible.

Comment: @Lucas Oh, sorry( I got used to that people use ```markdown``` like a synonym of ```Rmarkdown```  with ```r``` tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make a nice table from the CSV file and you do not mind doing some copying, you can try this workaround, which is not an answer to your question but worth mentioning.

Load the CSV for example in a sheet and copy the HTML output, and then paste from clipboard where you want to show it. Often, where markdown works, also HTML works, and then you would not need to code it in markdown.

If you can save the table in HTML right away, you can even skip the CSV step, but I guess you have to begin with the CSV file.